# How to read an array of integers from single line of input if size of array is given in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to read an array of integers from single line where size of array is given in python3.
Like read this to list.

```
5 //size

1 2 3 4 5  //input in one line
```

**while i have tried this**

```
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

but dont succeed how to give size.

**Please help**
I am new to python 3

Comment: You don't need the size if the number of numbers in the input matches it...

Comment: There are _two_ lines (the size and the list itself), so you'll need two calls to `input`

Comment: You can please clarify what you are trying to do? Your title says you want to read *one* line, the input shown are *three* lines.

Comment: like we do in c/c++, we have given a size of array and we give input in one line and it automatically takes the whole input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you got the array size before,

you do this first:

```
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

then you slice it

```
print(arr[:size])
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be for a coding competition site like hackerrank or codechef.  First you need to read the first line line with the size. Then read the second line with the data.  In python, you don't need to know the size of the data before reading it, so get the input and discard it.  Some other languages, you need to know the size of input data in order to read it in properly.

```
array_size = int(input())
arr = [map(int, input().split())][:array_size]
```

Comment: i have tried but several test case failed. for ex:- 
arr size is 3 but
entered 4 element, for this input it will give something like "index out of bound" or give error, but mine code will passed in python. how should i fix it.

Comment: I added a slice to restrict the list of data to the specified size

Comment: arr = list(map(int, input().split()))    is working.